# When Docker is in swarm mode running several replicated HTTP servers, how do we know which container browser hits?

Tags: docker, http, docker-swarm

I am a bit confused by replicas in Docker swarm mode.

Assuming we have one manager, which runs a web service (the *contained command* is an HTTP server) with several replicas. In other words, there are multiple tasks (i.e. containers) each running an HTTP server in an infinite loop waiting for inbound requests.

Now, a browser comes along and accesses the hostname and port (e.g. http://localhost:3000).

**Question**: Which container serves the HTTP files to the browser?

[**Rolling updates**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/): I am particularly keen to understand the above in the context of rolling updates. If we have several replicas of a service running across multiple containers, and the service is updated by gradually rolling the service out to each container, how do we know if the browser sees an old or new container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Swarm has built-in load balancers to expose the services you want to make available externally to the swarm. So you're not calling directly the containers but the load balancers. Swarm has an internal DNS component that automatically assigns each service in the swarm a DNS entry and then uses a the internal load balancer to distribute requests among services within the cluster based upon the DNS name of the service.

So, the load balancer receives the requests and dispatch them towards the containers. In case of multiple replicas, the load balancer is the component in charge of use one container or another. Refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/#load-balancing) for more details.

If you wish you can add an external load balancer to the swarm (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/#configure-an-external-load-balancer).

About the rolling updates, it's a way to gracefully deploy a new version and so minimize the application downtime.
In Swarm the rolling updates uses an option called Parallelism which indicates the number of service tasks to update simultaneously:

- N
- 1 by default
- 0 will update/rollback all at once

and an option called Update order:

- stop-first, that first stop the old service and then create the new service
- start-first, that first start the new service and then stop the old service

Assuming stop-first, during rolling updates, first the service will be disconnected to the load balancer and then replace with a new version of the service.

Internally, the Docker deamon sends a `SIGTERM` signal to tell a service to stop and a time options called `stop-grace-period` before to call the `SIGKILL` signal and kill the service.
If your connection does not finish on time the service will be restarted anyway after the `stop-grace-period` (default 10s) and you'll experience an error to handle on your application side.

Comment: Thanks Alez. This is still somewhat unclear to me: We have several replicas of a web service (HTTP server) running. Let's say there are 5 such replicas. I make some changes to my code and rebuild the image. I now want to update the service with that new image. If we use a rolling update, we gradually roll the update out over the 5 containers that before the update all ran the same service. Now, a browser comes and hits the server where the stack resides. Which HTTP server will respond to its request? One of the updated containers, one of the old ones, or is it random?

Comment: Side note: The way I understand load balancing (and I may be wrong) is that Docker assigns a DNS address to a service, like the *web* service. the *web* service might have many replicas represented as tasks (i.e. containers) spread across one or more nodes (i.e. hosts). SO, there might be 5 different identical versions of the HTTP server running in different containers. If the browser tries to access a server on a certain port, the load balancer will direct the browser to the correct service. But, it is still unclear to me which replica (i.e. which container) is chosen.

Comment: The link you sent to the docs states: *All nodes in the swarm route ingress connections to a running task instance*. So, it somehow picks a container. I do not understand how it picks.

Comment: The container to forward the request to is chosen with round robin scheduling. Even during rolling updates, there's no priority between the replicas, including for containers running newer version of the application.

Comment: That's super helpful, thank you. A quick related side question: Docker swarm seems to do rolling update by default (since parallelism is 1), with zero update-delay. Assuming we have one node, but create a couple of replicas, do we need to use start-first or such, to enable zero-downtime updates? Or, is it enough that it has two+ replicas, so it stops nr 2, starts new container, and in meantime serves visitors container 1?

Comment: By default parallelism is 1. Generally, I suggest to set start-first option (stop-first is the default one), in order to do in loop: 1. deploy the new container, 2. check if the new container is ok (here you have N+1 containers able to serve requests), 3. stop the old container. In this way, you are sure to always have a certain number of containers able to serve requests. In any case, you cannot reach a real zero-downtime updates, because if you have a long lived connection they will be cut sooner or later.